# Для чего нужен m4 макропроцессор?

Tags: linux, макросы, макрос

Прочитал все возможные статьи, но так и не понял. Зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что такое препроцессор в С и С++ понимаете? Что такое макросы понимаете? Так m4 - тот же препроцессор, только значительно более мощный.

Comment: Эх, как в Java не хватает настоящего, родного препроцессора!

Comment: ))))))))))

Comment: в С++ в он реже нужен (там есть шаблоны, которые по факту - те же макросы, но более навороченные). А вот в чистом С - препроцессор самое оно.

А в java препроцессор часто бывает очень нужным (к примеру, что бы сделать отладочную и релизную версию или lite/full).

"если чувствуете, что нужно скопипастить код, так как сделать отдельной функцией не получается, возможно нужны макросы".

Comment: Случай, когда даже в С++ препроцессор незаменим, - это условная компиляция, особенно для создания кроссплатформенного кода.

Comment: @KoVadim В современном C использование макропроцессора как правило ограничивается директивами #include (как и в ibm'овском PL/I) и #IF/#IFDEF (для условной трансляции). Всё остальное -- в лес (кроме #define для этих if'ов). Портянки #define'в, определяющих константы -- давить без малейшей жалости, вместе с теми, кто это пишет. Макросы с параметрами -- тоже в лес (inline есть)

Comment: это только говорит о том, что Вы не умеете использовать макросы.  Ведь макросы это не только набор `#define some thing`, а и очень интересные возможности.

В одной с моих программ есть макрос `E(f)`. аргумент - функция. Этот вызов разворачивается в if, который проверяет значение функции, если оно 0, то вставляет вывод в лог номера строки с ошибкой и имя функции и некоторую дополнительную работу. Сделать это функцией было бы сложно. Пришлось бы делать разворачивание стека.

В visual studio C++ они также используются оригинально.

Comment: @KoVadim это экзотика. Для таких штук можно использовать и независимый макропроцессор, включая те же cpp и m4. Но желательно, чтобы в программах, которые я буду читать, таких фокусов было поменьше. Если не хватает средств C, то можно подумать об использовании более высокоуровневого языка. А что касается использования макросов, то вспоминаются протонити (protothreads, фундамент ОС Contiki), но это, опять же, достаточно специфичный случай. В мире десктопов так лучше не делать, не прошлое тысячелетие.

Comment: > Но желательно, чтобы в программах, которые я буду читать, таких фокусов было поменьше

понятно, что если для компиляции кода нужен какой то нестандартный препроцессор, то это не экзотический случай. А стандартный препроцессор может очень сильно упростить написание кода.

> то можно подумать об использовании более высокоуровневого языка.

это не всегда возможно. К тому же С в умелых руках очень высокоуровневый язык.

> В мире десктопов так лучше не делать, не прошлое тысячелетие.

пользователю побоку. Главное что бы быстро и предсказуемо работало.

Comment: @alexlz, на тему inline есть


    #define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
     ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type  *)0)->member)))
    
    #define list_for_each(pos, head) \
     for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); \
             pos = pos->next)

это из linux list.h IMHO inline-ами не сделать

Comment: @alexlz В Netbeans'е в плагине для J2ME разработки есть препроцессор - замечательная штука. Когда программировал под Java Mobile реально сильно помогал. Конечно, есть сторонние примочки-препроцессоры для Java, но очень плохо, что это не есть встроенное средство. Конечно появились аннотации - нечто похожее, но все таки это не то.

Comment: @KoVadim, очень здорово. Это использовалось на этапе отладки?

Comment: Вы о E(f) ? и в отладке, и в продашине. Просто немного разные макросы.

А ещё мне нравится трюк от майкрософта, который в упрощенном виде выглядит так

    #define   malloc(s)             _malloc_dbg(s, __FILE__, __LINE__)

_malloc_dbg - специальная функция, которая вызывает реальный malloc и проверяет параметр. В случае ошибки может вывести номер строки.
В не дебажном режиме макрос вызывает реальный malloc.  В реальном коде там немного больше кода (crtdbg.h).

Comment: @KoVadim, на самом деле, использование специальных макросов для определения номера строки, имен файла и функции - довольно известная вещь. Встречал часто в самых разных местах. Сам пользовался )))

Comment: @avp да уж. С первым макросом -- как-то непонятно, откуда берётся ptr (т.е. адрес структуры неизвестен, требуется найти, но известен адрес поля этой структуры). Странная ситуация. Ну да всяк по своему с ума сходит.

А второй макрос напоминает C-- начала 90х (тот, который набор ассемблерных макросов, а не язык). Или более ранние упражнения такого типа. Прототреды, про которые я упоминал -- из подобных приёмов. Доп. сложности при чтении программ.

@KoVadim а вот макрозамена malloc -- это круто. Линуксоиды вроде до такого не опускаются, трюкачат на уровне линкера ld.

Comment: @alexlz, тут в комментариях места мало, поэтому текст, описывающий макросы я не копипастил. Если интересно: `ptr` из первого - это `pos` из второго макроса (обход циклического списка). 

Сотни программистов в тысячах строк ядра пользуют.

Comment: @avp Да я не против. И смотреть исходники ядра мне лень. Только показалось странным, что `ptr` (или `pos`) указывает не на начало структуры, а на какое-то её поле. Ну ладно, мне это не настолько интересно, чтобы разбираться.

Comment: @alexlz, согласен, поначалу структура, организующая список, размещенная внутри элемента списка (а не указывающая на его начало) выглядит странно. До тех пор, пока не потребуется одни и те же данные (структуру) одновременно размещать в разных списках.